# Not able to add to my sqllite table (may not be NULL (code 19))

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm trying to update my Sqllite table by adding some text but when i click save it doesn't appear and this gets shown in the log cat

```
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886): Error inserting summary=tryig to insert text
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: todo.category may not be NULL (code 19)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at com.oxpheen.notescheduler.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider.insert(MyTodoContentProvider.java:101)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:866)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at com.oxpheen.noteschedulerfree.SchedulenoteDialog.saveState(SchedulenoteDialog.java:273)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at com.oxpheen.noteschedulerfree.SchedulenoteDialog.onPause(SchedulenoteDialog.java:251)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
11-20 18:54:47.196: E/SQLiteDatabase(27886):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's line 251:

```
   @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState(); /////THIS IS IT
  }
```

And here's my saveState method (Line 273 contains a bunch of these ////)

```
  private void saveState() {
    //String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
    String summary = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    //String description = mBodyText.getText().toString();


    if (summary.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, summary);
   // values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

    if (todoUri == null) {
      // New note
      todoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values); 
          //This is line 273 above
    } else {
      // Update note
        Toast.makeText(ScheduleTweetDialog.this, "didnt do content uri",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     getContentResolver().update(todoUri, values, null, null);
    }
  }
```

If you could help me with this it'd be great. I just can't figure it out, been on it for hours. Thanks a lot! I will post anything else needed immediately!

EDIT: If I uncomment that I get this can't pause the activity error.

```
    11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree/com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3144)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog.saveState(ScheduleTweetDialog.java:266)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog.onPause(ScheduleTweetDialog.java:262)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
11-20 19:13:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(2717):     ... 13 more
```

My onpause method

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
  }
```

Redone savestate method

```
 private void saveState() {
    String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
    String summary = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String description = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    // only save if either summary or description
    // is available

    if (description.length() == 0 && summary.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, summary);
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

    if (todoUri == null) {
      // New todo
      todoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
      // Update todo
      getContentResolver().update(todoUri, values, null, null);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have evidentially defined your table with todo.category not null.  That means you cannot insert a null value into that column.

What's most likely happening (and you can verify this with the debugger) is that, in saveState(), category is null.  If that's acceptable in the rest of the program, then what you can do is this:

```
values.put (TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category == null ? "" : category);
```

This will put an empty string in the column rather than attempt to put null.

When you want to retrieve the value, you can do this:

```
String category = cursor.getString (col);
if (category.length == 0)
  category = null;
```

If you really need to distinguish between null and empty string, then it's better to change your table definition to allow nulls in this column.

Comment: But then I get a onpause error. I updated my question with the methods and stuff. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how an error in onPause() is related to doing the insert.  Are you doing the insert during onPause()?

Comment: Yes it runs the saveState method on the onpause. Just that the onpause isn't working I gues.

Comment: Ok, so your initial problem is solved.  I suggest you do a little debugging to to see what is causing the null exception in onPause and, if you need help, post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the insertion of value to CATEGORY:

```
//values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
```

So it tries to insert null to this column, and apparently this is not a valid value for this column (check your table definition to see why). So you need to actually insert some value to this column (e.g. uncomment this line)

Comment: Don't just check the length, first check if the variable is null.

Comment: Using this now values.put (TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category == null ? "" : category); and that solves that but now the error goes to my onpause as shown in the updated question